# New to this. Prime number function exercise advice

Tags: c++

If this isn't the best place to ask this question, please direct me to the best spot. In a book i have recently been working on it had an exercise that asks to write in main to test all the numbers from 2 to 20 and prints the results on separate lines. It wants me to use a prime number function and use a for loop in main. I am stuck and this is what I have so far.

(this is the revised code, and I am still trying to get it to work. having trouble pinpointing the problem.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int prime(int x);

int main() {
    int i;


    for(i=2; i <= 22; i++) 
        cout << prime(i) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int prime(int x) {
int i;

for(i=2; i <= sqrt((double)x); i++) {
    if(x % i == 0)

    return false ;
}
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Comment: Tidbit: you need a semicolon after the first `int prime(int x)`.

Comment: You've posted in the right place, but it's best to always provide as much information as possible e.g. explain what (incorrect) behaviour your program is displaying and/or copy+paste any error messages. Saying "I'm stuck" means that people reading the question have to waste time trying to figure out what you mean.

Comment: Hint: if you want to perform some test in your loop you need something like an `if` statement.

Comment: @user3148250, Also a performance advice: `i * i < x` is way faster than `i <= sqrt((double)x)`. `sqrt` is rather slow, and you have to work with doubles instead of ints.

Comment: @FreeNickname but, isn't this susceptible to integer overflow?

Comment: @JanDvorak, Good point. Considering the fact that we are talking about numbers between 2 and 20, it's not dangerous, but it's important to keep it in mind in general. Another, safer advice then: it's better not to calc `sqrt(x)` every time. Declare something like `int sqrtX = sqrt(x) + 1;` before the loop and check `i < sqrtX` in the loop.

Comment: @FreeNickname good idea about caching; doesn't the compiler alreadyy do that for you, however, making the whole issue moot?

Comment: @JanDvorak It (or he? how should I refer to a compiler?) might do it indeed (didn't check that). But I think it won't harm to do it manually. And since the OP is a beginner, I thought that it would be a good thing to point it out :)

Comment: @FreeNickname: It's a micro-optimization. Beginners need not worry. Whether the compiler can do this optimization depends on it knowing that `sqrt` is a pure function, whose return value is determined solely by its argument. (Which can be an issue on implementations with multiple rounding modes)

Comment: @MSalters: no, it isn't. Have a look: [Not optimized](http://ideone.com/nWmPsU), [Optimized](http://ideone.com/D87It2) (~10% faster for 1 million numbers). It isn't a 100% accurate benchmark, but it is enough to see the significant difference. Run these programs with `i` going up to 10000000 (ten million). I got up to 45% performance boost on my machine (compiler optimizations are off). I just know that recalculating a condition in `for` is often a bottleneck. I ran into this problem myself several times.

Comment: @MSalters, With -O3 the time is equal though. But still I think that it is better to remember that recalculating the loop condition on every step might cause performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `i % x` is the rest of division of `i` by `x` since `i < sqrt((double) x)`, `i % x` is always equal to `0`

You have to change your expression to `x % i == 0` to check if `x` is divisible by `i` so that its not a prime.

Also you have to add an `if` to return `false` only if `x % i == 0`. so:

```
if (x % i == 0){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Okay so i have tried to revise the code, but it is still not running. I switched the i and the x, added an if loop, and included cmath. I think one of the main problems im having is figuring out where the problem actually is. You guys have any tips on that? I edited my original code, to what i have now. Thanks for the all the quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
i % x == 0;
```

to

```
if (x % i == 0) // you want to check this true/false, so use it inside if()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 bool isPrime(int n){
if(n%2==0) return false;
int m=3;
while(m*m<n){
    if(n%m==0) return false;
    m += 2;
}
return true;
 }

 int main(){
int input;
cout<<"Please enter an integer: ";
cin>>input;
if(isPrime(input))
    cout<<input<<" is a prime number.\n";
else
    cout<<input<<" is not a prime number.\n";
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Your `isPrime` function returns 2 as __not__ prime.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a library `<cmath>`for the `sqrt`
and ";" in the decleraton of the prime function 
here is the working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int prime(int x);
int main() {
    int i;


    for(i=2; i <= 22; i++)
        cout << prime(i) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int prime(int x) {
    int i;
    int y= sqrt((double)x);
    for(i=2; i <= y; ++i) {
        if (x % i == 0)
        return false ;
    }
    return true;
}
```